# Change non-NaN values of a column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

|  | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Europe** | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| **France** | 5 | None | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| **Germany** | 4 | None | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| **Spain** | 1 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

Where Europe-Spain are indexes and Monday-Friday are column names.

I would like to replace all **non-None** values in a column to **0** if in that column, **Europe's** value is **0**.

So at the end the DF should look like this:

|  | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Europe** | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| **France** | 5 | None | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| **Germany** | 4 | None | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| **Spain** | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 |

I can't seem to find any elegant solution to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a first guess, could you create two masks (1) missing values (2) Europe = 0, and combine those with logical AND ?

Comment: I was thinking about something along those lines, but I am stuck with how to turn it to code

Answer (score 2):

Using a boolean mask:

```
m = df.loc['Europe'].eq(0)

df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].mask(df.loc[:, m].notna(), 0)
```

Another boolean mask with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
m = df.loc['Europe'].eq(0)

df[np.logical_and(df.notna().to_numpy(), m)] = 0
```

Or taking advantage of the fact that `NaN*0` equals `NaN`:

```
df.loc[:, df.loc['Europe'].eq(0)] *= 0
```

Output:

```
         Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
Europe       10      0.0          0        10      10
France        5      NaN          0         3       4
Germany       4      NaN          0         3       4
Spain         1      0.0          0         4       2
```

Intermediates:

```
# df.loc['Europe'].eq(0)
Monday       False
Tuesday       True
Wednesday     True
Thursday     False
Friday       False
Name: Europe, dtype: bool

# np.logical_and(df.notna().to_numpy(), m)
array([[False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

Comment: The 0 * NaN = NaN solution is really smart! Will definitely keep using this trick in the future, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @Lucas

Answer (score 1):

you can start wih finding columns with 0 in index Europe, then change with applymap value to 0

```
zero_columns = df.columns[(df.loc['Europe'] == 0)]

df.loc[:, zero_columns] = df.loc[:, zero_columns].applymap(lambda x: 0 if x is not None else x)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there a way to make the 0 an int while applying the lambda function instead of a float? The function changes it to 0.0 instead of just 0. This isn't a big issue, I was just wondering if I can do this within the function instead of fixing it after

Comment: @Lucas you can if you convert to object, but probably shouldn't as this type is less efficient to work with than numeric. Another option is to `convert_dtypes()` to benefit from the nullable integer type.

Comment: @LucasB.Bahadir i use data = {
    'Monday': [10, 5, 4, 1],
    'Tuesday': [0, None, None, 8],
    'Wednesday': [0, 7, 1, 2],
    'Thursday': [10, 3, 3, 4],
    'Friday': [10, 4, 4, 2]
} as dataframe and my value 0 not 0.0, but you can cast in to int - df[col].astype(your_type)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which first detects the columns where `Europe` is zero and then replaces the not `NaN` values by zero:

```
idx = df.loc[df.index == 'Europe'].eq(0).values.flatten()
d = df.loc[:, idx]
df.loc[:, idx] = np.where(d.isna(), None, 0)
```

Output:

```
         Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
Europe       10      0.0          0        10      10
France        5      NaN          0         3       4
Germany       4      NaN          0         3       4
Spain         1      0.0          0         4       2
```